# ROS_WORKSPACE is not supported with catkin workspaces?

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-workspace, ros-groovy, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Calling `roscd` with no arguments gives "No ROS_WORKSPACE set" error while using catkin workspaces in Groovy. So it is not supported anymore?

Is there any other way to quickly jump into either top level directory of catkin workspace or its development space?

Thanks,

Boris

---

**UPDATE**: Opened a [ticket](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/294).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51463/ros_workspace-is-not-supported-with-catkin-workspaces?/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-06**:
+1 for opening the ticket about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, currently no such tool exists.
However you can manually set ROS_WORKSPACE currently, to achieve either.

You could also raise a ticket on catkin to start a discussion if you feel others would benefit from such a feature.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4